# Is Aspose Cloud FDA Part 11 compliant?

Tags: aspose, aspose.words, aspose.pdf

The US FDA has regulations for electronic record keeping:

> TITLE 21--FOOD AND DRUGS
>   CHAPTER I--FOOD AND DRUG ADMINISTRATION
>   DEPARTMENT OF HEALTH AND HUMAN SERVICES 
>   SUBCHAPTER A--GENERAL
>
> PART 11    ELECTRONIC RECORDS; ELECTRONIC SIGNATURES

https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfcfr/CFRSearch.cfm?CFRPart=11

Q1. Is the Aspose Cloud service Part 11 compliant?

(The forums have no existing questions)

Q2. Are you using Aspose Cloud currently in a Part 11 compliant app, what are the pros/cons?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If we are supposed to be certified by an external authority then we are not compliant. Though while reading the [CFR document](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfcfr/CFRSearch.cfm?CFRPart=11), we found no reason to not comply this certification.

Aspose for Cloud provides [Cloud Storage](https://dashboard.aspose.cloud/) to its customers but we also let our customers use their own Cloud Storage or [some other third party Storage](https://docs.aspose.cloud/display/totalcloud/How+to+Configure+3rd+Party+Cloud+Storages) they are comfortable with. So you can use Microsoft Azure or Dropbox that are Part 11 compliant with our APIs as a storage provider.

In short, you should not rely on our system alone to get the compliance. But if you use our system from a system that is Part 11 compliant, we don't find any reason why we will break the compliance.

Comment: It would be a declaration Aspose makes that they have formally assigned to their system. Akin to how Box has done it.
https://www.box.com/industries/life-sciences-biotech/21-cfr-part-11